# Proving a function is bounded given the first derivative of the function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $f : [0, ∞) → \mathbb{R}$ be the solution of the ordinary differential equation

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2 +f(x)^2}$

satisfying $f(0) = 1.$ (You may assume that this solution exists, and is unique.) Prove that $f$
is bounded.

I'm not sure where to start with this question, is there specific theorems that I need to take advantage of? Is it an unimportant fact that this is an ODE?

Any tips would be very helpful!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I thought about integrating the function to begin with but I'm not sure how the $f(x)^2 $ would work in that situation. I thought the mean value theorem may help but again I don't know which aspect of this would be useful

Comment: The integrating both sides is a good idea. Here's a hint, $f'(x) > 0$. So now what?

Comment: Sorry do you mean $ \int \frac{1}{x^2+f(x)^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{1-f(a)}{-a} \mathrm{d}x $ this would b setting b=0 so $f(b)=1$. sorry i understand $f'(x) >0$ implies f is increasing but how does this help?

Comment: Since when does $f'(x) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ ? The object on the left is in general a nonconstant function, the object on the right is a number, they cannot be equal.

Comment: Sorry I understand that fact. I am not understanding what is needed to complete this question unfortunately

Comment: What happens when you integrate $f'(x)$ ?

Comment: you get function f

Comment: Exactly, so $\int_0^x f'(t)\:dt = \cdots$ ? And then how could you bound the resulting expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>1$ we have $f(x)=f(1)+\int_1^{x}f'(t)dt \leq f(1)+\int_1^{x} \frac  1 {t^{2}}dt=f(1)+1-\frac 1 x <1+f(1)$. Hence $f$ is bounded on $(1,\infty)$. Any continuous fucntion is bounded on $[0,1]$. Hence $f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f'(x) > 0$, which means that $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing. Thus,

$$f(x) = 1+\int_0^x f'(t)\:dt = 1+\int_0^x\frac{1}{t^2+f(t)^2}\:dt $$

$$\implies |f(x)| \leq 1 + \int_0^{|x|}\frac{1}{t^2+1}\:dx = 1 + \arctan|x| \leq 1 + \frac{\pi}{2}$$